# Data with same row name into column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The data I tried to process are in replicates like this:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOcT1.png)

I want to plot them with error bar, can I plot them as it is?
I was trying to make them look like this, so I can plot them:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVrf3.png)

I tried to use pivot table, but seems like it only works on data with at least two labels
Thank you very much!

Comment: please post your data, rather than image. and any code you've used to try and solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I checked it, and it works also with one label):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t = ['treatment_1', 'treatment_1', 'treatment_1', 'treatment_2', 'treatment_2', 'treatment_2']
n = [10, 12, 13, 20, 22, 23]
df = pd.DataFrame(t, columns=['treatment'])
df['value'] = n
table = df.pivot(columns=['treatment']).replace(np.nan, 0)
table = pd.DataFrame({c: table.loc[table[c] != 0, c].tolist() for c in table})
print(table)
```